# How can i completely reset a tableview to show differently structured data in the same tableview?

Tags: javafx

I'm writing an JavaFX-Application to work with PostgreSQL-databases (SQL-Queries, visualising database objects). One part of the application is a tableview that displays the results of SQL queries.

The code to populate the tableview with the result of the query is based on [this article](https://blog.ngopal.com.np/2011/10/19/dyanmic-tableview-data-from-database/) and works flawless for the first query; there is a column for each attribute of the query and the data is shown in the tables cells.

My problem is, that the tableview attaches the columns of subsequent queries right of the existing columns from previous queries; the table grows to the right side column-wise.

I tried to remove the existing columns with no success by calling (`tableview.getColumns().removeAll()`), but the columns are not removed from the table. Calling the tableviews `refresh()` method has also no effect.

Example:

Query 1:

```sql
SELECT name, sex
FROM person
LIMIT 10;
```

Query2:

```sql
SELECT title, year
FROM production
LIMIT 3;
```

Content of my tableview after these two queries:

```
name | sex | title             | year
-------------------------------------
     |     | Paris Pursuit     | 1960
     |     | Call Out the kids | 1960
     |     | No Bong Bongos    | 1960
```

Am i overseeing anything here?

Edit: correct removeAllColumns() to removeAll()

Comment: don't invent api (getColumns().removeAllColumns() doesn't exist and won't even compile) nor apply existing api randomly ... simply read and understand the api doc and apply what's appropriate :) Hint: look at the type returned by table.getColumns, read the api doc of that class (and its ancestors) to find out how to remove everything contained.

Comment: btw: _tableview attaches the columns of subsequent queries right of the existing columns_ is wrong - it's your code (which you are not showing :) that does, most probably by call list.add (vs. f.i. list.setAll)

Comment: okay, but then's something wrong in the code you are not showing ;) Please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: `removeAllColumns()` was a careless mistake on my side, i meant `removeAll`. And your assumption was correct; i was adding columns by `list.add`in a for-loop. `list.setAll` leads to the desired behaviour. I will provide a mre later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

kleopatra's assumption was indeed correct. I misunderstood the usage of `removeAll()` and assumed it would clear the list while the method only removes the columns passed as arguments. Adding new columns in a for-loop with `list.add()` instead of gathering them in a list and adding them with `setAll()` added insult to injury.

So thanks for setting me on the right track, kleopatra.

sample.fxml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.ScrollPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.SplitPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TableView?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>

<SplitPane dividerPositions="0.9" maxHeight="400.0" maxWidth="600.0" minHeight="400.0" minWidth="600.0" orientation="VERTICAL" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/11.0.1" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="sample.Controller">
  <items>
    <AnchorPane minHeight="0.0" minWidth="0.0" prefHeight="100.0" prefWidth="160.0">
         <children>
            <ScrollPane layoutX="60.0" layoutY="52.0" prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="200.0" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="0.0">
               <content>
                  <AnchorPane maxHeight="360.0" maxWidth="600.0" minHeight="360.0" minWidth="600.0" prefHeight="360.0" prefWidth="600.0">
                     <children>
                        <TableView fx:id="dataTable" layoutX="14.0" layoutY="14.0" prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="200.0" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="0.0" />
                     </children>
                  </AnchorPane>
               </content>
            </ScrollPane>
         </children></AnchorPane>
    <AnchorPane minHeight="0.0" minWidth="0.0" prefHeight="100.0" prefWidth="160.0">
         <children>
            <Button fx:id="regenerateButton" layoutX="255.0" layoutY="5.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#regenerateData" text="Regenerate" />
         </children></AnchorPane>
  </items>
</SplitPane>
```

Main.java

```java
package sample;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception{
        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("sample.fxml"));
        primaryStage.setTitle("Hello World");
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 600, 400));
        primaryStage.setResizable(false);
        primaryStage.show();
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Controller.java

```java
package sample;

import javafx.beans.property.SimpleStringProperty;
import javafx.beans.value.ObservableValue;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn;
import javafx.scene.control.TableView;
import javafx.util.Callback;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.UUID;

public class Controller {
    @FXML
    private TableView dataTable;

    @FXML
    public void regenerateData() {
        Random rand = new Random();
        int columnCount = rand.nextInt(50);
        int rowCount = rand.nextInt(300);

        ObservableList<ObservableList> tableData = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

        ArrayList<TableColumn> columns = new ArrayList<>();

        for(int i = 0; i < columnCount; i++) {
            final int j = i;

            TableColumn col = new TableColumn(UUID.randomUUID().toString());

            col.setCellValueFactory(new Callback<TableColumn.CellDataFeatures<ObservableList, String>, ObservableValue<String>>() {
                @Override
                public ObservableValue<String> call(TableColumn.CellDataFeatures<ObservableList, String> param) {
                    return new SimpleStringProperty(param.getValue().get(j).toString());
                }
            });
            columns.add(col);
        }

        for(int i = 0; i < rowCount; i++) {
            ObservableList<String> row = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

            for(int j = 0; j < columnCount; j++) {
                row.add(UUID.randomUUID().toString().replace("-", ""));
            }

            tableData.add(row);
        }

        dataTable.setItems(tableData);

        dataTable.getColumns().setAll(columns);
    }
}
```